# Sum of float - 'float' object is not iterable

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for match in matches:
    p = float(match.split()[0])
    print(p)
```

Code above gives the following result:

```
2.14
6.06
6.89
```

However if I try to sum those numbers

```
print(sum(p))
```

I receive an error 'float' object is not iterable

Comment: `p` is the last float not an iterable (like a list) of floats

Comment: please advise on down votes so I can improve

Comment: append `p`s to a list (or use a comprehension) then you can sum the values, or just use `p += ` to sum as you go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're basically trying to take the sum of `p`, which is a `float` ergo your error. If you want the sum of all the floats you should store them in a structure and then sum over that:

```
myFloats = [float(m.split()[0]) for m in matches]
print(myFloats)
print(sum(myFloats))
```

I used a list comprehension here to store all the floats in a list but it does the same thing as your for loop. If you'd prefer to use the for loop you can use `myFloats.append` instead. Alternatively, if you just want to sum your data and don't care about any other storage then you can use `map` like this:

```
print(sum(map(lambda x: float(x.split()[0]), matches)))
```

As an aside, a great way to fix similar errors for yourself in the future is to use the `type` method. Thsi will tell you what the type of your variable is. For instance, `print(type(p))` would return "float", which would've told you that you weren't working with an iterable.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this worked great. Can anyone advise on the down vote on my question so I can improve?

Comment: @user3508766 I posted some edits for clarity. I think the downvote might've come about because you said you were trying to get the "sum of floats" but you were only taking the sum of one float. I disagree with it but there are some pretty harsh people here. Don't worry to much about it

Answer (score 2):

'p' is a single float, sum() works on lists of numbers. This should work:

```
numbers = [float(match.split()[0]) for match in matches]
sum(numbers)
```

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: yehehe! not by much, though.

Comment: You're needlessly making a list object. Try `sum(float(m.split()[0]) for m in matches)`

Answer (score 0):

Your variable p is just a float object .Its not a list of float objects.Try this

```
p=[]
for match in matches:
    p.append(float(match.split()[0]))
    print(p)
print(sum(p))
```

Answer (score 0):

`p` in your code refers to a single `float`, not a list. Try this:

```
p_list = []
for match in matches:
    p = float(match.split()[0])
    print(p)
    p_list.append(p)
print("Sum is {0:.2f}".format(sum(p_list)))
```

Here, you accumulate the individual `p` values into a list called `p_list`, then apply a sum to it and print the result. (`"{0:.2f}"` is a format specifier to print a `float` with 2 decimal places.)

Answer (score 0):

Store the values of p in a list or array then do `sum`.

```
plist = []
for match in matches:
    p = float(match.split()[0])
    plist.append(p)

sum(plist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simple store addition in a new variable and no need to create a new bulky list

```
float_sum=0
for match in matches:
    p = float(match.split()[0])
    print(p)
    float_sum+=p
```